# Laravel 5.3 cannot use select value from collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to calculate the price including tax of a product in an ecommerce app. In table tax i have the following columns:

```
id - iso_code - vat.
```

My query to obtain vat information for a particular countryid:

```
    $taxRate = DB::table('tax')
        ->select('vat')
        ->where('iso_code', $productcountryid)
        ->get();
```

If I print_r the $taxRate value I obtain

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] 
=> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [vat] => 1 ) ) )
```

To retrieve vat value I used:

```
    $taxRates=$taxRate[0]['tax'];
```

and I obtain the following info:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

On the other hand, using

```
$taxRates = $taxRate->vat;
```

> Error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$vat

My idea is to use $taxRate value to obtain a simple calculation

```
priceamount = $productprice * $taxRate
```

UPDATE using @assada suggestion ------

```
    $array = $taxRate->toArray();
(array)[0]['vat']
```

gives error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

any help appreciated about how to process the value returned in a collection.
brgds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

You can use some like this:

```
$taxRate = DB::table('tax')
    ->select('vat')
    ->where('iso_code', $productcountryid)
    ->get();
$collection = collect($taxRate);
$array = $collection->toArray();
```

or just try

```
 $taxRate = DB::table('tax')
    ->select('vat')
    ->where('iso_code', $productcountryid)
    ->get();
 $array = $taxRate->toArray();
```